# Underline block element with different font sizes without an interrupted line

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to underline an `block` element that contains text. The block has an `font-size` attribute and the text within the `block` is surrounded by an `inline` element which has a different `font-size` attribute.

Is there any way to ensure, that the line resulting from the `text-decoration="underline"` of the outer block is a straight line over all the block element (without any 'gaps' - please see the attached picture) that is not changing its position with the font-size ?

My code:

```
<fo:block font-size="14pt" text-decoration="underline">
    Some text
    <fo:inline font-size="10pt"> text with a smaller font size </fo:inline>
    Another text
</fo:block>
```

My result:

[image: Problem with undelined block with different font sizes]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have two versions of XSL-FO engine from one supplier, and the most up-to-date version renders a common underline without gaps, while the older version renders what you see with FOP.  So it seems to be implementation dependent.

But you can mimic the appearance of what you want by selectively using the border rather than relying on the implementation:

```
  <block font-size="14pt">
    <inline border-after-width="1pt" border-after-style="solid">
Some text
<inline font-size="10pt"> text with a smaller font size </inline>
Another text
    </inline>
   </block>
```

Whether this mimic works in FOP or not, I don't know as I don't use FOP.

Comment: +1, but one should be aware that in most rendering engines, the bottom border is a bit lower than an underline would be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, bottom border is lower than underline, but that's just fine for me.